# In SQL Server, how do I select the rows that were unchanged in a table after a trigger was used?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Inside a trigger, I want to not only get the previous values of the rows that were changed (DELETED table) but also the values of the rows that weren't changed at all.

Would this work?

```
SELECT * FROM DELETED
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Table.Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
```

Comment: *"Would this work?"* What happened when you tried? Presumably you are implying it *didn't* work? What happened that wasn't desired/expected?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Usually, rest of the table shouldn't be needed (signed by someone who wrote hundreds of triggers)

Comment: Surely that would just be `SELECT * FROM Table`? That'll contain both the affected and unaffected rows. It's unclear what objective you're trying to fulfil here.

Comment: @siggemannen I'm trying to compare how many rows there are in the table before the trigger and after the trigger, so I need not only the affected rows but also the unaffected rows.

Comment: Depends what type of trigger this is, @Damien_The_Unbeliever , and the desired behavour. If this is an `UPDATE` trigger, the OP may not want the *new* values; the requirement is unclear.

Comment: @ThomA In the question I was trying to get the old values from either affected or unaffected rows, so I think that solution will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say

> I'm trying to compare how many rows there are in the table before the trigger and after the trigger

You don't actually need to query the whole table, which is very inefficient. You can just compare `inserted` and `deleted`

```sql
DECLARE @diff bigint =
    (SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM inserted)
  - (SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM deleted);
```

This works in a trigger which handles all of `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`.

If you have just a `INSERT` or `UPDATE` trigger you only need to query `inserted`.

```sql
DECLARE @diff bigint = (SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM inserted);
```

If you have just a `DELETE` trigger you only need to query `deleted`.

```sql
DECLARE @diff bigint = (SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM deleted);
```

If you need the full amouont of rows in the table, the fastest (if not always perfectly accurate) way of doing it is:

```sql
DECLARE @TotalRows bigint = (
    SELECT SUM(st.row_count)
    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
    JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = st.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schame_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE t.name = 'MyBigtable'
      AND s.name = 'dbo'
      AND st.index_id < 2
);
```

This result is *after* changes have been applied, so subtract the previous result to get the before value.